# Python 3 Beginner- Code loop

Tags: python, loops, calculator

I am having trouble with my code. Every time I try anything from scratch with python 3 I end up with endless loops. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Here is a calculator that I am trying to get to work...

```
loop = 1 # 1 means loop; anything else means don't loop.
choice = 0 # This variable holds the user's choice in the menu

while loop == 1:
    # Print what options you have
    print ("Welcome to StandardCalculator.py")

    print ("your options are:")
    print (" ")
    print ("1) Addition")
    print ("2) Subtraction")

    print ("3) Multiplication")

    print ("4) Division")
    print ("5) Raise to the Power")
    print ("6) Quit StandardCalculator.py")
    print (" ")

choice = input("Enter choice(1/2/3/4):")
if choice == 1:
        add1 = input("Add this: ")
        add2 = input("to this: ")
        print (add1, "+", add2, "=", add1 + add2)
elif choice == 2:
        sub2 = input("Subtract this: ")
        sub1 = input("from this: ")
        print (sub1, "-", sub2, "=", sub1 - sub2)
elif choice == 3:
        mul1 = input("Multiply this: ")
        mul2 = input("with this: ")
        print (mul1, "*", mul2, "=", mul1 * mul2)
elif choice == 4:
        div1 = input("Divide this: ")
        div2 = input("by this: ")
        print (div1, "/", div2, "=", div1 / div2)
elif choice == 5:
        pow1 = input ("Raise this: ")
        pow2 = input ("by: ")
        print (pow1, "**", pow2, "=", pow1 ** pow2)                     
elif choice == 6:
        loop = 0

print ("Thank-you for using StandardCalculator.py!")
```

Comment: In `while loop == 1`, you never change the value of `loop`. Why are you looping that part anyway?

Comment: When will the `while` loop evaluate to `False` if your value is always the same?

Comment: You'll also have a problem with `if choice == 1` etc. I suggest you go back and review your textbook's relevant sections.

Comment: No offense, but this is like not being able to figure out a math problem because you're holding the pencil upside down. You'll have a much smoother time of this if you stop and learn the basics of the language first.

Comment: You should take two numbers once, after the choice making sure to cast to ints, you might also find a dict with operator.add, operator.sub etc..  as values to remove the need for multiple if's. You should also compare `choice` to strings i.e `if choice == "1":`

Comment: This question has proved to be a great example of [the FGITW problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here ultimately is indentation. Currently, your while loop will just keep printing your prompt and never allow you to enter a choice or to apply logic to that choice.

Also, when you get your `choice` input, it is in String format and you are comparing it to an int. Let's assume the input is valid, you have two choices:

1. `int` that.

   ```
   choice = int(choice)
   ```
2. Compare to strings

   ```
   if choice == "1":
       ...
   elif choice == "2":
       ...
   ```

Once you fix the indentation and the type issue, check out AndreL's answer.

```
loop = 1 # 1 means loop; anything else means don't loop.
choice = 0 # This variable holds the user's choice in the menu

while loop == 1:
    # Print what options you have
    print ("Welcome to StandardCalculator.py")

    print ("your options are:")
    print (" ")
    print ("1) Addition")
    print ("2) Subtraction")

    print ("3) Multiplication")

    print ("4) Division")
    print ("5) Raise to the Power")
    print ("6) Quit StandardCalculator.py")
    print (" ")

    choice = input("Enter choice(1/2/3/4):")
    choice = int(choice)
    if choice == 1:
            add1 = input("Add this: ")
            add2 = input("to this: ")
            print (add1, "+", add2, "=", add1 + add2)
    elif choice == 2:
            sub2 = input("Subtract this: ")
            sub1 = input("from this: ")
            print (sub1, "-", sub2, "=", sub1 - sub2)
    elif choice == 3:
            mul1 = input("Multiply this: ")
            mul2 = input("with this: ")
            print (mul1, "*", mul2, "=", mul1 * mul2)
    elif choice == 4:
            div1 = input("Divide this: ")
            div2 = input("by this: ")
            print (div1, "/", div2, "=", div1 / div2)
    elif choice == 5:
            pow1 = input ("Raise this: ")
            pow2 = input ("by: ")
            print (pow1, "**", pow2, "=", pow1 ** pow2)                     
    elif choice == 6:
            loop = 0

print ("Thank-you for using StandardCalculator.py!")
```

Comment: AndreL's answer omits some key parts, without which the program still won't work (same with yours).

Comment: Just compare the choice to a string, you only need to cast to an int if you actually plan on using it.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't included the choice part into the loop, tab everything after `print (" ")` so it is included into the while loop.

Also change the if statements from `if choice == 1` to `if choice == "1"` choice will be string not int.

Lastly when working out the answer you need to change the input which is string into integers so change

`print (add1, "+", add2, "=", add1 + add2)`

into something like:

`print (add1, "+", add2, "=", int(add1) + int(add2))`

If you did it lazily like I did your program will crash if the user inputs something that can't be converted into string so you have to include a `try` in there too.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: misread the problem.

You're not changing the value of 'loop', therefore it will always equal 1. I think this is what you were aiming for:

```
while loop == 1:
    # Print what options you have
    print ("Welcome to StandardCalculator.py")

    print ("your options are:")
    print (" ")
    print ("1) Addition")
    print ("2) Subtraction")

    print ("3) Multiplication")

    print ("4) Division")
    print ("5) Raise to the Power")
    print ("6) Quit StandardCalculator.py")
    print (" ")

    choice = input("Enter choice(1/2/3/4):")

        if choice == 1:
            add1 = input("Add this: ")
            add2 = input("to this: ")
            print (add1, "+", add2, "=", add1 + add2)
        elif choice == 2:
            sub2 = input("Subtract this: ")
            sub1 = input("from this: ")
            print (sub1, "-", sub2, "=", sub1 - sub2)
        elif choice == 3:
            mul1 = input("Multiply this: ")
            mul2 = input("with this: ")
            print (mul1, "*", mul2, "=", mul1 * mul2)
        elif choice == 4:
            div1 = input("Divide this: ")
            div2 = input("by this: ")
            print (div1, "/", div2, "=", div1 / div2)
        elif choice == 5:
            pow1 = input ("Raise this: ")
            pow2 = input ("by: ")
            print (pow1, "**", pow2, "=", pow1 ** pow2)
        elif choice == 6:
            loop = 0
        else:
            loop = 1;


print ("Thank-you for using StandardCalculator.py!")
```

Notice that I added an 'else' to set loop to 1. This way if someone makes an invalid choice, it will not break but instead will continue the loop once more.

Take care with the indentation, your code was stuck printing the six options because the loop originally only contained the print statements. Your indentation didn't include the rest of the code which would have allowed for a break condition.

```
while loop == 1:
    # Print what options you have
    print ("Welcome to StandardCalculator.py")

    print ("your options are:")
    print (" ")
    print ("1) Addition")
    print ("2) Subtraction")
    print ("3) Multiplication")
    print ("4) Division")
    print ("5) Raise to the Power")
    print ("6) Quit StandardCalculator.py")
    print (" ") # <- End of loop

choice = input("Enter choice(1/2/3/4):") # <- Outside loop, needed to be indented.
```

Lastly, after fixing that your code would have run fine, but I removed some indentation in your else/if's, Python should ideally be indented by 4 spaces.

Ideal:

```
    if choice == 1:
        add1 = input("Add this: ")
        add2 = input("to this: ")
        print (add1, "+", add2, "=", add1 + add2)
        loop = 0
```

Not ideal:

```
    if choice == 1:
            add1 = input("Add this: ")
            add2 = input("to this: ")
            print (add1, "+", add2, "=", add1 + add2)
            loop = 0
```